# Can I check results before applying filter in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Is there something built into ag-grid that will tell me if applying a filter will return no results?

I'm using custom filters on a grid with ~20,000 rows. I've not found anything in the docs that hints this is something ag-grid has built in.
My current (theoretical) method is to set the filter, count the rows and then clear the filter without applying the model so the UI doesn't update but I have the info I need.
This feels messy and will no doubt have performance issues.

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not a feature of ag-grid.

I also don't think that your theoretical method will work, as the grid won't actually apply the filter until you "apply the model" - your count will be the count of all rows, since you haven't really applied the filter yet.

The only way that I can think to do it is to get the prospective filter model, and then filter through the data yourself.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I realised I couldn't get any meaningful information about the number of rows before the model was actually applied.

I ended up using `.forEachNodeAfterFilter` with `onFilterChanged` to check the data in the remaining rows. It was surprisingly fast for 20,000 rows.